# Determine MIN Date from Consecutive Occurrences

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that contains the following columns: Date, Customer, Active Flag.  I need to add a fourth column called Start. The Start column should return the first date the client was active, based on consecutive active flags.

[image: This image]

shows the three columns I currently have and the results I wish to return for the Start column.

Your insight into what my SQL code should look like to achieve this would be appreciated.  Thanks!!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without subqueries, if I assume one date per month per customer:

```
select t.*,
       (case when activeflag = 1
             then coalesce(max(case when activeflag = 0 then date end) over (partition by customer order by date) + interval '1 month',
                           min(case when activeflag = 1 then date end) over (partition by customer)
                          )
        end) as start
from t;
```

Subqueries, though, might make this easier.  You can treat this as a gaps-and-islands problem:

```
select t.*,
       (case when activeflag = 1
             then min(date) over (partition by customerid, seqnum - seqnum_a)
        end) as start
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid, activeflag order by date) as seqnum_a
      from t
     ) t
```